# How many days with birthdays are in a classroom?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-distributions, birthday

**Assumption:**

I am a teacher of a classroom with *n* students. And every time there is one or more birthdays in a day, I will buy only a cake.

**Question:**

How many cakes do I have to buy on average every year?

**Extra info:**

In a different question in this forum ([The birthday-cake problem: a variation on the birthday problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1739739/the-birthday-cake-problem-a-variation-on-the-birthday-problem)), the solution is given as `Solution=365−365(364/365)^n` but because the question was different, the solution is not explained. I need an explanation or a reference to learn more about it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you have just made up this question by yourself ? More information is needed, particularly, how many days of classes the teacher is scheduled to take in an year.

Comment: Note two important things: Expected value is linear, so given constants $\alpha,\beta$ and random variables $X,Y$ you have $E[\alpha X+\beta Y] = \alpha E[X]+\beta E[Y]$, and note that letting $X$ represent the total days which are birthdays and $X_i$ the indicator random variable $X_i=\begin{cases}1&\text{if day }i\text{ is a birthday}\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$, recognize that $X=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{365}X_i$.  It follows that $E[X]=E[\sum\limits_{i=1}^{365}X_i]=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{365}E[X_i]$

Comment: I still remember this famous problem taught by our proffesor Yogeshswaran And My batchmate X and Y got matched with 47 weight of class, Very nice problem , With 25 weight there is hardly match but there still a approx mediocre chance of matching. A very nice problem.

Comment: @JMoravitz, I don't understand your comment

Comment: @ErnestoGómez I was justifying why we can "just multiply by 365"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Choose a particular day.  The chance a given student does not have a birthday on that day is $\frac{364}{365}$.  The chance all the students do not have birthdays on that day is $\left(\frac{364}{365}\right)^n$ so the chance that at least one student has a birthday on that day is $1-\left(\frac{364}{365}\right)^n$.  The chance is the same for every day, so the expected number of days that you buy cakes is $365\left(1-\left(\frac{364}{365}\right)^n\right)$.  If you only buy cakes on school days, change the leading $365$ to the number of school days per year.

Answer (score 2):

The probability that a fixed day is not a birthday is (assuming independence)
$$
\left(1-\frac{1}{365}\right)^n=\left(\frac{364}{365}\right)^n
$$
since we multiply the probabilities for each of the $n$ students.
So the expected number of days that are not birthdays is
$$
365\times \left(\frac{364}{365}\right)^n
$$
which gives the expected number of days that are birthdays as
$$
365-365\left(\frac{364}{365}\right)^n
$$
matching the answer you quoted.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, very clear and it was the first one, but I found another answer easier to understand

Comment: no problem. I'd appreciate an upvote on the answer.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation for voting yet :(